# Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have set up your Android development environment:

Tags: react-native

I tried to run the react-native run-android through my React Project on Ubuntu. After that, I got an error like the following.

-> src git:(master) ✗ react-native run-android 
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory '/Home/Bin/Android/sdk' does not exist.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:622:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/biz/Documents/Lathashree/Djamm/src/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/home/biz/Documents/Lathashree/Djamm/src/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/home/biz/Documents/Lathashree/Djamm/src/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)

Comment: its saying it cant find android sdk folder, also most of the times that builds fails due to any exception it says `Make sure you have an Android emulator running...'` so don't get distracted, look at the error before this message, the real problem is mentioned there

Comment: Yes After I connected my phone i was able to run! Thanks @Amas